# Does $\{gBg^{-1}\}_{B\in\mathcal{B}}=\mathcal{B}$?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of all Borel subgroups of $G$. Denote the identity component of subgroup $H\subset G$ by $H^\circ$.

I want to show that $$\mathscr{R}G=\left(\bigcap_{B\in \mathcal{B}} B\right)^\circ$$
is a normal subgroup of $G$.

---

I think I have the rough idea down, but it's not 'clicking'.

- So I consider $g\in G,b\in \mathscr{R}G$, then since $b$ is in every $B\in\mathcal{B}$,$$gbg^{-1}\in gBg^{-1}$$ for each $B\in \mathcal{B}$, but by the conjugacy theorem, each of these is some Borel subgroup $B'\in \mathcal{B}$.

> - I haven't yet proved this, but I believe that by the conjugacy theorem $$\{gBg^{-1}\}_{B\in\mathcal{B}}=\mathcal{B}$$ for any $g\in G$. (Is this true?)

- So I can conclude $gbg^{-1}\in B$ for every $B$ and hence $gbg^{-1}\in \cap_{B\in \mathcal{B}} B$, now I just need to consider the identity component.

Comment: I edited the question to highlight probably the fundamental thing that isn't understood. Although perhaps the outline is still wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that "if $B$ is a Borel subgroup, then $gBg^{-1}$ also".
On the other hand, for each Borel subgroup $B$, $B=g(g^{-1}Bg)g^{-1}=gB'g^{-1}$ is also the form $gB'g^{-1}$ for some Borel subgroup $B'$. Hence
$$\{gBg^{-1}\}_{B\in\mathcal{B}}=\mathcal{B}.$$

So 
\begin{align*}
g(\mathscr{R}G)g^{-1}&=g\left(\bigcap_{B\in \mathcal{B}} B\right)^\circ g^{-1}\\
&=\left(g\left(\bigcap_{B\in \mathcal{B}} B \right)g^{-1}\right)^\circ\\
&=\left(\bigcap_{B\in \mathcal{B}}g B g^{-1}\right)^\circ\\
&=\left(\bigcap_{B\in \mathcal{B}} B \right)^\circ\\
&=\mathscr{R}G.\\
\end{align*}
This follows by the map
     \begin{aligned}
  f: & G  \to G \\
   & x \mapsto gxg^{-1}
 \end{aligned}
is a homeomorphism.
Hence $\mathscr{R}G$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you sir/madam!